# What is this classical piece

Tags: classical-music

Apologies for the poor recording. We heard this playing and its really annoying us that we cant figure it out!

https://cruholdingsltd-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/scott_cruholdings_com/EdYCaVIQE7RJuo2NmQzMt90BUnJU0ZGNaK0pMNs0Ar6xVg?e=FLBZ8K

Comment: By any chance, did you hear it from a De Beers commercial?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it's from the first movement (the most famous movement) of [*Palladio*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32Ag0dBGbvc) by Karl Jenkins.

Comment: @ScottMurray If the answer is what you were looking for, you should accept it (the green tick mark) and upvote it.